# How to maximize area of a square inscribed in a equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, maxima-minima

We have an equilateral triangle and want to inscribe a square, in such way that maximizes the area of the square.

[image]

I sketched two possible ways, not to scale and not perfect.

**Note I am not sure if the second way will really have all square corners touching the triangle sides.**

The second case appears to have bigger side-lengths of the square, so bigger area. But I do not know how to determine the angles involved. How to solve this?

Comment: @TobyMak This isn't a duplicate, since OP is asking which of two specific configurations is better.

Comment: **How do you define _"inscribed"_?** In your first sketch, one corner of the square is actually floating, not touching the triangle. I think it is safe to assume that there is only one way to inscribe a square in an equilateral triangle, and it is when one side of the square lays exactly on one side of the triangle (as in your second sketch). As a result, the problem of maximization is a non-problem.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Are they? Because that's not the question asked in the title.

Comment: @JackM It is in the consideration of the title problem that the real question has been asked.

Comment: A very nice problem indeed!  Do you consider the first case to be symmetric also,  like the answer below?  Or just in general,  with just 3 of the tips of a square,  touching the triangle and the fourth just somewhere inside the area of the triangle?

Comment: @dmtri I wanted to consider all possible cases, which is infinite, so I only drew two.

Comment: @DrZ214, How do you know that the squares with exactly three corners on the given triangle and the fourth one inside that triangle, they are infinite in number?

Comment: @dmtri The square with 3 corners touching the triangle, can be rotated about 15 degrees to become a square with all 4 corners touching the triangle. The square sides adjust in length during this rotation. There are an infinite number of numbers between 0 and 15, so there are infinite cases. Of course, i picked the two edge cases, and it should be continuous and increasing all throughout them, so only those two edge cases are really necessary to analyze.

Comment: @DrZ214, I think there is only one square with all its corners on the triangle with side length $l$. This square has side-length $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}l$. As far as the squre with exactly $3$ corners on the triangle, there is at least one as it is shown in your nice first scheme. Can you provide - construct another one, please? You may put it as an answer to your question, if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum area of a square inscribed in an equilateral triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545594/what-is-the-maximum-area-of-a-square-inscribed-in-an-equilateral-triangle)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be the side lengths of the two squares. To determine which one is larger, we simply look at their ratio below.

With the angles in the diagram,

$$d_1=\frac{1}{2\tan 30}a_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a_1$$
$$d_2=\frac{\sin 15}{\sin 30}a_2=\frac{1}{2\cos 15}a_2$$

Assume both equilateral triangles have unit height.

$$1=a_1+d_1=\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)a_1=\frac{1}{2}(2+\sqrt{3})a_1$$
$$1=\sqrt{2}a_2+d_2=\left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\cos 15}\right)a_2=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})a_2$$

So, their ratio is

$$\frac{a_1}{a_2}= \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2+\sqrt{3}} =\left(\frac{8+4\sqrt{3}}{7+4\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} > 1$$

Answer (score 3):

The second configuration (square has edge contact with triangle) indeed has a bigger inscribed square. If the square has unit sides, the triangle's side is [$1+\frac2{\sqrt3}$](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squintri):

[image]

The symmetric first configuration may be resolved as follows. Set the unit square's bottom corner as $(0,0)$, so that the top corner is $(0,\sqrt2)$. Let the side length of the triangle be $r$. Then we have, by similar triangles,
$$\frac{(\sqrt3/2)r-\sqrt2/2}{\sqrt2/2}=\sqrt3$$
$$r=(1+\sqrt3)\sqrt{\frac23}=2.230\dots$$
and this is greater than $1+\frac2{\sqrt3}=2.154\dots$, so the first configuration has a smaller inscribed square than the second.

Comment: Maybe,  you mean the second,  in your the sentence before last?

Comment: @dmtri I got my words right there, checking again.

Comment: Sorry , you are right , you are talking about the sides of the triangle not the square....

Answer (score 2):

Let sides-lengths of the equilateral triangle be equal to $1$.

Let $x$ be sides-lengths of the square in the first configuration.

Thus, by law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{\sin60^{\circ}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sin75^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\frac{x}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}}$$ or
$$x=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2(1+\sqrt3)}$$ and for the area of the square we obtain:
$$\frac{3}{2(4+2\sqrt3)}=\frac{3}{4}(2-\sqrt3).$$

Let $y$ be sides-lengths of the square in the second configuration.

Thus, by similarity we obtain:
$$\frac{y}{1}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-y}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}$$ or
$$y=\sqrt3(2-\sqrt3)$$ 
and for the area of the square we obtain:
$$3(7-4\sqrt3),$$ which is a bit of greater.